# MAMP servers running but displaying "Oops! Google Chrome could not find localhost:8888"

Tags: php, mysql, osx-snow-leopard, mamp

I'm trying to run MAMP on Snow Leopard. The servers are green and working but whenever I go to any browser I get, more or less, the "Oops" message from Chrome. I can't figure out what the issue is?

In my apache_error.log I get:

```
[Sun Dec 02 14:03:40 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Dec 02 14:03:40 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Dec 02 14:03:40 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 PHP/5.4.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Dec 02 14:14:12 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Dec 02 14:14:13 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication...    
[Sun Dec 02 14:14:13 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Dec 02 14:14:13 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 PHP/5.4.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Dec 02 14:27:55 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Dec 02 14:43:56 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Dec 02 14:43:56 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Dec 02 14:43:56 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 PHP/5.4.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Dec 02 15:04:14 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Dec 02 15:04:18 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Dec 02 15:04:18 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Dec 02 15:04:18 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 PHP/5.4.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Dec 02 15:04:24 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Dec 02 15:04:27 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Dec 02 15:04:27 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Dec 02 15:04:27 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 PHP/5.4.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

And the mysql_error_log.err is:

```
121202 15:04:27 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql
121202 15:04:27 [Warning] You have forced lower_case_table_names to 0 through a command-line option, even though your file system '/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/' is case insensitive.  This means that you can corrupt a MyISAM table by accessing it with different cases. You should consider changing lower_case_table_names to 1 or 2
121202 15:04:27 [Warning] One can only use the --user switch if running as root

121202 15:04:27 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
121202 15:04:27 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121202 15:04:27 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
121202 15:04:27 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
121202 15:04:27 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
121202 15:04:27 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121202 15:04:27 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
121202 15:04:27 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
121202 15:04:27 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 8889
121202 15:04:27 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
121202 15:04:27 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
121202 15:04:27 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
121202 15:04:27 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.25'  socket: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 8889  Source distribution
```

Any help?

Comment: are you sure that apache is configured to listen on 8888?

Comment: Can you connect to localhost:8889 ?

Comment: @GabrielSantos - Mysql listens on 8889 with MAMP.

Comment: @GabrielSantos No, I tried that, nothing

Comment: @lupatus, it's configured to listen on 8888. That's one of the reasons I'm confused why it's not working correctly

Comment: There is nothing unusual in those logs you list. What does your hosts file look like (from terminal:  `cat /etc/hosts`) ?

Comment: try going to `http://127.0.0.1:8888` or run `telnet 127.0.0.1 8888` in terminal - see if anything is listening there. In `/etc/hosts` you should have at least that line: `127.0.0.1 localhost`

Comment: @lupatus adding 127.0.0.1 localhost was it! Works great now, thank you very much!

Comment: Don't forget to add the second portion of what you will need... see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You said your Hosts file is empty so it sounds like the computer just doesn't know what "localhost" is. Try adding the following to it (copy this exactly):

```
127.0.0.1   localhost

255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

then quite MAMP and restart. See if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Chrome was behaving quite weird for me.  Initially it loaded http://localhost/mypage.htm just fine.  But then when I hit refresh (F5), it gave the error message above, saying it couldn't find that server ("perhaps localho.st?").  And then at other times it was failing to load related js files.  Adding these entries in the HOSTS file fixed the issue.  No reboot required (for me, running Windows 7).